# Is it possible to get number of active connections with Pusher from API

Tags: pusher

Is it possible to get number of active connections with Pusher (http://pusher.com/) from the API?

Can't find it in the their Python server library they're supporting. I can see it on the stats page in their web based dashboard though, but I want to present it to my users in the browser.

Comment: I work for Pusher, I would love to hear why you would want access to this stats. can you email me at sylvain(at)pusher(dot)com ? Ty

Comment: Sure @Syl, just sent an email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a subscription_count attribute to the get-channel method in the REST API:

http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api#method-get-channel

but you will need to get special access:

> [BETA] Number of connections currently subscribed to this channel. This attribute is not available by default; please contact support@pusher.com if you would like to beta test this feature.

Comment: This isn't "connections" - it's subscriptions. The docs wording doesn't help! Connections are actual network connections whereas you can have multiple subscriptions over the same connection. See How are Connections counted: https://pusher.tenderapp.com/kb/accountsbillingplanspricing/how-are-connections-counted AFAIK there isn't a way of querying the number of connections via the API. You'd need to add your own application logic to determine that or have a channel that all users subscribe to and then use a subscription count on that channel to work out number of connections.